# Accessing navigation parameters Expo-Go

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have got "Screen1" where I create a string "blabla". According to the documentation, I can set it as a navigation parameter:

```
export default function Screen1() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  navigation.navigate("Screen2", { item: "blalbla" });
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Render some stuff</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

On Screen2 I should be able to access it with:

```
export default function Screen2({ route, navigation }) {
  const { item } = route.params;
  console.log(item);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Render some stuff</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Now, this returns:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.item')]
```

I also tried some other examples without success.

Referring to React-Native documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a Snack. Check [this](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/navigation) out.

Follow below steps to solve your problem

Create a Folder called `navigation` where your `App.js` is located.

Then inside this folder create a file called `AppNavigator.js`

Inside `AppNavigator.js` paste this

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Screen1 from '../screens/Screen1';
import Screen2 from '../screens/Screen2';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function AppNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default AppNavigator;
```

Now create another folder called `screens` where your `App.js` is located

Inside this folder create your two files `Screen1.js` and `Screen2.js`

They should look like this

`Screen1.js` -

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

function Screen1({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Screen 1</Text>
      <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen2', { item: 'blalbla' })}>
        Press ME
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default Screen1;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

`Screen2.js` -

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

function Screen2({ route, navigation }) {
  const { item } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Screen 2</Text>
      <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen1')}>{item}</Text>
      <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen1')}>Press ME</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default Screen2;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Now you should see `route parameters` inside `Screen2`

Comment: I removed my useNavigation() and added navigation.navigate to a button but I get: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')]

Comment: show your `stackNavigator` or your `Navigation` part

Comment: const Screen1Stack = createStackNavigator<Screen1ParamList>();

function Screen1Navigator() {
    return (
        <Screen1Stack.Navigator>
            <Screen1Stack.Screen
                name="Screen1"
                component={Screen1View}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
        </Screen1Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

Comment: Thanks, man. I am working on it and try to transfer it to my project. At the moment, I think the problem is my StackNavigator. I will let you know tomorrow...

Comment: Sure!. I use this approach in all my projects. I hope it helps you

Comment: Great job! With your help, I could rearrange my StackNavigator. I deleted the common BottomStackNavigator and could rebuild my project with your structure. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

navigation object is probably not present in the screen

change `Screen1({  navigation })` to `Screen1(props)` and do `console.log(props)` to check if you see a `navigation` object there

Comment: No, it returns:   
    "params": undefined,